# how to set JAVA_HOME enviroment on linux for Appium Doctor using

Tags: android-studio, appium-android, automation-testing

i currently for using appium, i need to install appium doctor for automation testing. When i run appium doctor in my terminal there was error in line of terminal [[image: this is my terminal when i run appium doctor]]

`export ANDROID_HOME= $HOME/Android/Sdk` export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools export JAVA_HOME=  export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
`export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator`
`export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH``

i have put this but still error